# Charge after turning off an electronic device

Tags: charge, physics, earth

Let's say I've just turned off my Raspberry Pi and put a imaginary boundary around it.

Everything not on this picture is outside the boundary.
[image]

Is the net charge, inside the boundary, neutral?

Comment: I suggest you better explain what you really are interested in. It is not clear wheteher it is a theoretical question about basic physical concepts or is it a practical question about ESD hazzards. Do you really care about Rapberry Pi in particular or is it just an example...

Comment: where's the power supply, unplugged or still connected?

Comment: @Neil_UK I turn my Rasp Pi off by unplugging the micro-USB cable from the power supply. (After software shut down.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more or less, most of the time.

The state of the capacitors has little or no bearing on the net charge.

If the air is (or was) moving fast over the Pi, it might hold a static charge, for instance. If it was radiated with ionizing radiation, I expect the Pi would be ionized to some degree.

It all depends.

Comment: Okay, i was thinking that maybe the capacitors are holding a certain charge, which would drain, after turning off the circuit board, and thereby 'give' the circuit board some overall net charge. I don't know whether this means "surplus of electrons" or "deficiency of electrons" inside the boundary.

Comment: Capacitors do not store *net* charge at all - charge on one plate is balanced by its absence on the other.

Comment: @pjc50 Thanks, you're right! So, when taking a snapshot of a circuit board within the imaginary boundary, it doesn't matter whether it's turned on or off? The net charge is always neutral? Always equal number of protons and neutrons?

Comment: Protons and electrons, neutrons are chargeless. The only time you have to worry about *net* charge normally is tribocharging - plastic shoes on synthetic carpets and so on. Humans can build up a surprising charge.

Comment: @pjc50 Sorry :-) My mistake/typo. I meant: always equal number of protons and electrons? (Within the imaginary boundary.)

Comment: @marty Yes. Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: Does any object that comprises trillions of atoms really have zero net charge? I imagine the chances would be infinitesimal, simply because nature is messy. My intuition tells me that every object on a macroscopic scale must have at least some miniscule non-zero absolute charge, merely due to randomness, radiation, nuclear decay, etc., unless someone with the proper know-how and equipment deliberately and very carefully sets out to balance it? OTOH, the universe as a whole seems to have neutral charge... https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1izb6c/what_is_the_net_charge_of_the_universe

Answer (score 0):

Probably.

If you just unplugged it from a grounded power supply, then yes.

If you were powering it from a battery, with the whole assembly sitting on a charged surface, then no.

Comment: The Pi is powered by an AC-to-DC adapter without earth-prong. So not a grounded power supply. Does that change your answer?

Comment: Whether it can build up charge depends on the exact construction of the PSU, but usually even the isolated ones have some (many megaohm) resistors connecting the AC side to the output ground.

Comment: I'm using just a simple smartphone +5V power adapter. 2 prongs. With an USB to micro-USB cable in between.

Comment: @Marty make no mistake, the gound and the earth go to the same place.